# jinja2 returns text instead rendered icon

Tags: flask, jinja2

My html output is

```
<a href="#">{{title}}</a>
```

I want to have a result like

```
<a href="#"><fa class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></fa></a>
```

I try

```
title = '"<fa class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></fa>"'
```

but it does not work. I get a text `"<fa class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></fa>"`, not the icon.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second set of quotes

```
title = '<fa class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></fa>'
```

Comment: then I got &lt;fa class="fa fa-fw fa-retweet"&gt;&lt;/fa&gt;